c# Data grid view (performance) async
I wanted to know which one is used to achieve the best performance overall
loading data into (Data grid view) control with auto size for columns, or used
a fixed size column , also wanted to know if (async) in my code used properly or not ..
code (Presentation layer , desktop form:


 private async void frmListPeople_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     _dtPeople = await Task.Run(() => clsPerson.GetAllPeople());

     if (_dtPeople.Rows.Count > 0)
     {


         dgvPeople.DataSource = _dtPeople;
//auto..
         dgvPeople.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
         cbFilterBy.SelectedIndex = 0;
         lblRecordsCount.Text = dgvPeople.Rows.Count.ToString();
     }

//OR manually 
            //    dgvPeople.Columns[0].HeaderText = "x";
            //    dgvPeople.Columns[0].Width = 110;
  //    dgvPeople.Columns[0].HeaderText = "y";
            //    dgvPeople.Columns[0].Width = 110;

 

I tried both ways , I tried to trace which one is better   , I wanted someone has experience with this thing , to suggest for me what trades off to each one if any

You have this post tagged as asp.net, and thus we are ALL assuming this is a web applcation. As such, the await can't be used, nor does it help. It can help for desktop, but with the asp.net tag, then the context of my answer below is a web page, and with the asp.net post-back model, then using await will not help, since all code behind must 100% finish and complete before the page is sent back to the client side browser. Thus introduction of a await can't and will not work nor help. There is a HUGE and Mount Everest difference here between desktop and asp.net . asp.net = web based application

Worrying about some extra spaces in the output? That is 100% waste of your time, and will not affect performance of the GridView in any noticeable way at all.
Markup sent to the browser in general does not send the blank spaces anyway, but will use markup and CSS styles to obtain the layout.
It is the browser side processing that can and will manage spacing and layout for you.
Take this simple GridView:
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    Width="45%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

And code behind to load:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblhotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable dtHotels = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataSource = dtHotels;
        GVHotels.DataBind();

    }

And the result is this:

Now, that above result looks really bad. So, you can do two things to improve how the GridView looks.
You can hire a graphics designer, one with years of experience in layout, font size, font spacing etc., and the result will look really nice.
Or, you can use someone's else's huge investment who already spent boatloads of money to improve the layout (that's called Bootstrap).
So, in above, let's add the Bootstrap class table, table-hover, and watch what happens:
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped"
            Width="45%">

And now the GridView looks like this:

Wow! - does that not look oh so much better?
And more amazing is the markup sent to the client side is quite much the same in the above two examples. It is the magic of adding Bootstrap class(es) to the GridView. The result is now nice spacing and nice layout. In fact, the GridView is now even responsive (it will re-size based on the browser window size).
So, we can now remove the size (width) and use this markup:
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID"
            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
            <Columns>

And the result is now a responsive GridView.

So, the layout and spacing is handled by the client side and thus it is not really a question of sending extra spaces etc. that matters. The CSS and styling occurs client-side and the client-size browser is thus free to change and setup the layout and spacing for you. So, things like spacing etc. are now handled client-side by the browser anyway.
Note how markup sent to the browser is quite much the same in both cases, but the magic of CSS and layout does all the work client side for the resulting layout. This again means that little worry exists in terms of the markup and things like extra spaces being sent. The browser does all that spacing and layout work client side for you anyway.
As for the asynchronous code? No, that will not help in ANY way, since all code has to wait, finish BEFORE the web page is sent to the client browser.
In other words, since all code behind must finish, then you gain nothing by using "await" to wait for everything to finish. If using await, then that defeats the whole purpose of asynchronous software, and with that await, then the software has to wait, and thus your resulting code is not asynchronous anyway, is it? So, no advantages are to be gained by using asynchronous code here.
What will matter for GridView (or near all data aware controls) is keeping the number of rows pulled from the database to a minimum.
And then even MORE important than reducing the rows pulled from the database, is further reducing the rows sent to the client browser side.
Remember, while CPU and processing has massive improved in say the last 10 years, the speeds of the network and that of sending the markup from the server to the client side browser has NOT improved much speed wise.
So, you can pull from the database say about 300 rows max. Anything more is too large of a data pull and too much load on the database server. However, pulling of such data does not affect the bandwidth and number of rows (markup) to the browser side. It is you the developer that has to limit and control the number of rows sent client side after that data been pulled.
So, once you achieved the database pull of data, then the next step is to reduce the rows sent to the client-side. So, while we don't worry about a few extra spaces here and there? We most certainly need to limit and reduce the number of rows sent to the client-side browser. This will achieve the most gains in performance from a user point of view.
So, to reduce rows sent to the client side, then adopting a data pager for the GridView solves this second issue and goal (reducing the rows and hence the amount of markup sent to client side).
In other words, while the data source might be 300 rows, you only want to send to the client side about 20, or maybe 30 rows at one time. (any more rows is simply too much data to send to the client-side browser).
Keep in mind that the built-in data pager "fakes" how it works, and does not use nor represent true database server paging of the rows sent.
In other words, you can suffice or use a design in which about 300 max rows are pulled from the database (even 300 rows are pushing things too high here).
However, using a GridView data pager, then you only then send about 20-30 rows at one time max to the browser.
If the data set is larger then about 300 rows, then you need to adopt server-side database paging for good performance. In other words, you don't pull 300 rows, but only pull the 20-30 rows you want to display in the browser for each page of data.
This means you have to dump use of the built-in data pager. And thus, you have to adopt designs in which code behind only pulls the number of rows you wish to display client side (about 20-30 rows max) from the database.
The above approach is how you obtain fantastic performance.
The above tips will increase performance of your GridView by 100s of times.
So, no worry exists about a few extra spaces in the page. You will not gain nor notice or realize any performance gains going down that path of reason and logic. And with CSS and style sheets, the spacing and layout occurs client-side anyway.
So, then using the above lessons, then let's load up a GridView with 12 million rows.
Our markup is this GridView
<div style="float: left">
    <asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server"
        Text="Load database of 12 million rows"
        OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"
        CssClass="myshadow" />
</div>

<div style="float: left; margin-left: 25px">
    Database row count = 
    <asp:Label ID="lblRows" runat="server" Text="">
    </asp:Label>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GVHistory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
    Width="50%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateStamp" HeaderText="Date"
            DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}" ItemStyle-Width="160px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyEmployeeID" HeaderText="Emp ID" ItemStyle-Width="80px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ComputerNetworkName" HeaderText="Computer Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Notes" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />

<asp:LinkButton ID="cmdPrevious" runat="server"
    CssClass="myshadow" Style="float: left"
    OnClick="cmdPrevious_Click">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-lg"> Previous</i>
</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Label ID="lblPageOn" runat="server" Text="1"
    Style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px; font-size: x-large">
</asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblOn" runat="server" Text="of"
    Style="float: left; font-size: x-large">
</asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblNumPages" runat="server" Text="22"
    Style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 20px; font-size: x-large">
</asp:Label>


<asp:LinkButton ID="cmdNext" runat="server"
    CssClass="myshadow" Style="float: left"
    OnClick="cmdNext_Click">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Next&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>

And the code behind is this:
const int PagerSize = 18;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Get one time row count from database
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo_ContactHistory";
        DataTable rst = 
            General.MyRst(strSQL, Properties.Settings.Default.AxisMIS);
        lblRows.Text = rst.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        cmdLoad.Text = $"Load {((int)rst.Rows[0][0]).ToString("N0")} rows of data";
    }
}

void LoadGrid()
{
    int iOnPage = int.Parse(lblPageOn.Text);
    string strSQL =
        @"SELECT * FROM dbo_ContactHistory ORDER BY dbo_ContactHistory.DateStamp
        OFFSET((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsPerPage) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;";

    SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pagenumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iOnPage;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@RowsPerPage", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PagerSize;

    DataTable rstData = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL, Properties.Settings.Default.AxisMIS);
    GVHistory.DataSource = rstData;
    GVHistory.DataBind();   
}

protected void cmdPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iPageOn = int.Parse(lblPageOn.Text);
    if (iPageOn > 1)
    {
        iPageOn --;
        lblPageOn.Text = iPageOn.ToString();
    }
    LoadGrid();
}

protected void cmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iPageOn = int.Parse(lblPageOn.Text);
    int NumPages = int.Parse(lblNumPages.Text);

    if (iPageOn < NumPages)
    {
        iPageOn ++;
        lblPageOn.Text = iPageOn.ToString();
    }
    LoadGrid();

}

protected void cmdLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iRows = int.Parse(lblRows.Text);
    int intPages = iRows / PagerSize;
    lblPageOn.Text = "1";
    lblNumPages.Text = intPages.ToString();

    LoadGrid();
}

So, the formula for data paging with SQL server is this:
@"SELECT * FROM dbo_ContactHistory ORDER BY dbo_ContactHistory.DateStamp
OFFSET((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsPerPage) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;";

Note how absolutely instant the GridView loads despite having a table with 12 million rows.
And note how blistering fast the data paging works when using next/previous to page the data.
Since we are only pulling 18 rows at one time from the database, and then only sending 18 rows to the client browser side, then we obtain performance that works without any noticeable delay at all. The next/previous navigation occurs absolutely instantaneous. Note how there are 718,456 pages of data for the 12 million rows.

So, concentrate on reducing the rows pulled from the database. And then limit the rows sent to the browser.
The result as above shows is absolutely instant response time and instant performance, despite working with a GridView that can display 12 million rows.
